# cannot bind ‘T’ lvalue to ‘T&&’

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Почему я не могу сделать так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <class Type, template <class, class = std::allocator<Type> > class Container>
void print_container(Container<Type>&& container, ostream& os) {
    os << "{ ";
    for (auto& var : container) {
        os << var << " ";
    }
    os << "}";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<string> name;
    name.push_back("Igor");
    name.push_back("Andrii");

    print_container(name, cout);
    //print_container(vector<string>{"Igor", "Andrii"}, cout); // Работает без ошибок

    return 0;
}
```

Получаю ошибки:

> ```
> example.cpp:22:31: error: cannot bind ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ lvalue to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&&’
>      print_container(name, cout);
>                                ^
> example.cpp:8:6: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘void print_container(Container<Type>&&, std::ostream&) [with Type = std::basic_string<char>; Container = std::vector; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’
>  void print_container(Container<Type>&& container, ostream& os) {
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

напишите

```
print_container(std::move(name), cout);
```

да и по-хорошему print_container константную ссылку должна принимать, а не r-value refenece...
хотя не, тут универсальная ссылка, так что норм...
хотя не все-таки r-value(увидев другой ответ)

Comment: Да это просто пример.
А без move как-то можна что нибудь придумать?

Comment: без move  сигнатура print_container должна принимать const Container<Type>& container

Comment: да понял спасибо

Answer (score 10):

Проблема в Вашем коде в том, что шаблонные шаблонные параметры [не дают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45790970/template-template-parameters-and-forwarding-references) на выходе пробрасывающую ссылку (*forwarding reference*). Но, судя по всему, Вы пытаетесь её использовать без понимания зачем она нужна, т.к. в Вашем примере нет никакого кода, который бы подразумевал пробрасывание типа.

Из-за вышеописанной проблемы у Вас получается функция, которая первым параметром принимает rvalue-ссылку, но Вы передаёте туда lvalue-объект, поэтому компилятор ругается. Правильным выходом в этой конкретной ситуации будет использование `const Container<Type>& container` в качестве аргумента функции. Ведь Вы не меняете контейнер и не передаёте его никуда: другие варианты здесь просто избыточны.

Но если отвлечься от всего вышесказанного, то можно заметить ещё одно: Вам совершенно не нужен шаблонный шаблонный параметр, ведь Вы нигде не используете то, что вывели благодаря ему! Поэтому если переписать пример так:

```
template <typename Container>
void print_container(Container&& container, ostream& os) {
    os << "{ ";
    for (auto& var : container) {
        os << var << " ";
    }
    os << "}";
}
```

, то он станет

1. Проще.
2. Имеющим пробрасывающую ссылку (хотя она и не нужна).

---

Код из вопроса позволил найти [баг](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/97849/msvc-doesnt-compile-valid-code-with-template-templ.html) в MSVC.

Comment: Тогда в цикле `auto&&`

Comment: @int3, внутренней «отделкой» функции пусть автор сам занимается.

Comment: А как такое вообшще возможно - `template <class Type, template <class, class = std::allocator<Type> > class Container>` - без указания имени параметра? Откуда компилятору знать, какой тип параметр должен быть? Почему не так - `template <class Type, template <class Type, class = std::allocator<Type> > class Container>`? кстати, так Visual C++ легко понимает...

Comment: @Mikhailo, имя там вообще роли не играет, а параметр по умолчанию может быть выставлен вне зависимости от наличия имени. Если сделать по-вашему, то это передекларация уже существующего `Type`, и в результате получается ерунда. То, что студия это проглатывает это ещё один её баг.

Comment: Не понял... это что, можно объявлять, скажем, `template<typename> class T;` и потом использовать `T<int>`, например?

Comment: @Mikhailo, я Вам рекомендую почитать про шаблонные шаблонные параметры в книге по C++, всё-таки комментарии на SO не очень удобны, чтобы крупные вещи обсуждать. Тем более, что они хороши описаны в учебниках.